# how can I fix text garbling of JSON on laravel?

Tags: json, laravel

how can I fix text garbling on JSON laravel?
I would like to check the data with no text garbling.

//MySQL Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)

```
Controller

    public function returnJsonTest(Request $request)
 {
        $sample =  DB::table('table')->whereDate('scheduled_date', '=', $searchDateTest)->get();

        return $sample;
 }
```

,"body":"\u5bfe\u5fdc\u53ef\u53ef\u80fd\u30a8\,created_at":"2020-06-03 00:50:01","updated_at":"2020-04-27 ...

DB=> MariaDB => utf8mb4_unicode_ci

database.php

```
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
//...omit
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```